# 18.04 networkctl equivalent for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, 18.04

On Ubuntu 18.04 I have used the networkctl tool to identify the port number of the switch that an ethernet interface is connected to, like so:

```
networkctl status eno3
<snip>
Connected To: CSW1 on port 515 (ge-0/0/6.0)
```

This tells me that the cable is running to port 6 on the switch. Is there an equivalent for Ubuntu 14.04?

I have been looking at the usual ethtool, ifconfig, netstat and ip commands... but cannot find an equivalent command that will identify the external switch port that the network cable connects to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm grateful to you, That's why I want to help you now!

**Ok, answering your Question you have to know 5 things...**

1. The Ubuntu new packages can be installed in old versions of Ubuntu.
2. The Ubuntu old packages can be installed in new versions of Ubuntu.
3. But you may have to correct the depenedencies.
4. With a same distro is not necessary the Equivalency.
5. networkctl is a internal feature of the package systemd

Knowing it, now i will explain to you how you can install networkctl in ubuntu 14.04

**Step number 1 (Safe Method) Build dependencies**

1. download a livecd of ubuntu that correspond to your installed ubuntu architecture and version, Note: have to be the exact version, no variants, example: if your installed version is 14.04.2 i386, you have to download the version 14.04.2 i386 live cd, for build the dependencies of the package that contains networkctl WITHOUT AFFECTING YOUR INSTALLED UBUNTU, you can find all ubuntu versions here:

[Ubuntu Livecd - Old releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

2. Run the live cd, and when you are in the desktop, is time to connect internet, and go to this page in your browser:

[Systemd package that contains networkctl](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/systemd)

3. In the bellow part, click in the architecture that match with your livecd architecture, for example i386 or amd64.
4. In the next part find where say: "You can download the requested file from the pool/main/s/systemd/ subdirectory at: " then now click in the link that say "security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu"
5. A .deb package will be downloaded, will be like systemd_x-x_x.deb
6. Now is time to build the dependencies(not compile), only fetch or download, for it you will need the package gdebi-core, for it type this command without quotes "gedit /etc/apt/sources.list", and now copy all lines in any file to backup your sources.list and now erase all lines and paste this text without quotes "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main"
7. Now save the file sources.list, and now is time to install gdebi-core, using these commands:

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
8. After the installation of all success correctly, is time to start to find or fetch the dependencies for the package systemd, for it use this command without quotes "gdebi /path_of_the_downloaded_systemd_deb_file/yoursystemd_downloaded.deb" and after it, gdebi-core will check the dependencies of the package, and will be installed, but not configured if some dependency are not satisfaced.
9. Now if you see Dependency is not satisfiable: Some_Dependience, then is time to find it dependency, you can search the dependency name in google for example: "some_ddependecy-someversion" and add launchpad.net at the ends with a space like this: "some_depend-some_version launchpad.net", and you will find the dependency, if the version and name match, is time to download it from launchpad or from other sources that you know are confiable, and install it dependencie, you will need do it too for the sub dependencies of a dependecy of the package systemd, graphicaly like a tree explainded:

`systemd:
--somedepend1
----subdepend1 of somedepend1
----subdepend2 of somedepend1
--somedepend2
----subdepend1 of somedepend2
----subdepend2 of somedepend2`

and you will need to use the same command for the depends and sub depends example "gdebi somedepend" and "gdebi subdepend_of_somedepend"

10. After all dependency are installed, is time to reinstall de package systemd, to resume te configuration, you will see a message that says a info of the package, and gdebi will ask you to continue Y/N, and lets type "y" letter without quotes, and the package will installed correctly.
11. The finish!, is time to copy all deb packages that you already download(systemd, and all deb files of dependencies), and paste it in your local disk where are installed your ubuntu, for example: "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/your_custom_name_for_the_dir_package", and after it, is time to reboot and eject the livecd, and now install all packages in your ubuntu installation, use this command to install:

    dpkg -R -i /home/ubuntu/Downloads/your_custom_name_for_the_dir_package

Note: Here are a various sites of repositories where you can find the dependencies of the package, or a exact systemd package for trusty without updates.

http://pkgs.org
http://packages.ubuntu.com
http://launchpad.net
https://packages.debian.org

Note2: If some package or dependency, are broken(have compatibility problems), you can solve it using these commands:

```
dpkg-deb -R somedepend.deb /home/youruser/some_path_to_extract
```

And modify the control file located in debian dir inside a extracted package and, modify the depends to fix problems, for example, versions, or names if are you obtaining depends from diferents distributions like (debian, fedora) etc.

And use the command to rebuild the package:

```
dpkg-deb -b /home/youruser/some_path_to_extract somedepend.deb
```

And reinstall the fixed dependency!.

FINISH!!

I suggest not install packages from a high distant versions like for example: Trusty and Cosmic, because will be so much more difficult, i recommend install any package from the next version... in this case Xenial that is the next of Trusty.

Maybe this method is so tedious, but unfortunately after the end of the support to ubuntu trusty, the packages only can obtained manually, and not at all in oficial sources. Good Luck

Comment: There is no proof that this really answers the question. Getting the info could also be dependent on the Ethernet driver. So, long and complicated procedure, perhaps for nothing?

Comment: Ok, then i have a question for you!
Your question is about a Package that you need? or About a driver that you need? or BOTH?

Comment: No worries about proof, just i want help you, like you do it to me before, just try my method if you need a package, but if you have problems with a drivers in ubuntu sorry, you will need not only the package that contains networkctl(systemd), you will need identify the device, and download the correct driver in ubuntu, but drivers packages can't be builded on livecd. keep it in your mind!

Comment: Anyway keep in mind too, that in ubuntu is rare have problem with drivers, ubuntu contains drivers automated, that ajusto to all versions of the manufacturers, not at all, but in general yes, in general the most big problems are: "the people does not install the necesary packages to make ubuntu works good in sircumstances where ubuntu not works properly by default"

Comment: Hi there, I have edited my question for clarity. Sorry to have caused confusion. I asked how to identify an external switch port, using Ubuntu 14.04. It was not a problem with package searching. Thank you for trying though, I appreciate it. Be careful that you don't get down-voted!

Comment: Ok, no problem, much better :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step number 2 (Unsafe Method) Run the direct executable networkctl** - EASY

Download the package according the architecture of your system in the link below:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/systemd

And, extract the deb package using this command:

```
dpkg-deb -R systemd_xxxx.deb some_directory_to_extract
```

and now in nautilus(file manager), navigate into the extracted dir files, and search "networkctl" without quotes.

copy it executable in any location that you want to run, and now give the right permission to excecute, using this command "chmod 0755 /yourselected_some_path/networkctl" without quotes

and now use the command "cd yourselected_some_path", and now run the networkctl, typing this command "./networkctl" without quotes.

Comment: Nice idea, actually, but unfortunately the networkctl tool is part of the systemd-networkd service group, and as such doesn't work stand-alone. Ubuntu 14.04 uses ifupdown. "dpkg -S /etc/init.d/networking" --> "ifupdown: /etc/init.d/networking".

Comment: Yes, So sorry, i hope you have good luck, and find a more easier method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was investigating, and networkctl in ubuntu trusty is a default included feature, apparently.

**Have you try before to check if the service are running with this command line, before to use the command?**

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd
```

If you got a output like this:

`● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)`

Then you will need type these commands, for enable it:

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctlenable systemd-networkd
```

After it, networkctl have to work properly...

Other way more exactly, to answer your question is: **Switch from Systemd-Networkd to Networkmanager?**, Networkmanager is a alternative to systemd-networkd.

Follow these commands to switch:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
```

And for dns server:

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Here the documentation source:

http://xmodulo.com/switch-from-networkmanager-to-systemd-networkd.html

I can't find of anything else!